# Quitar Corchetes de una cadena texto y conservar la palabra JavaScript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

Estoy empezando con JavaScript y empieza a agradarme por las funcionalidades que tiene.

me encuentro con este problema

tengo una cadena de texto con lo siguiente **"1. ME GUSTA USAR [ JAVASCRIPT ] VERSION 1.1 "**

Que deseo, conservar la palabra JAVASCRIPT sin los corchetes

Con esto logro obtener la palabra junto con los corchetes es decir **[ JAVASCRIPT ]**

```html
<script>
var p = '1. ME GUSTA USAR [ JAVASCRIPT ] VERSION 1.1 "';
var PrinActi = /\[.*?\]/g;
var PrinAct2 = p.match(PrinActi);
console.log(PrinAct2);
</script>
```

Ahora necesito que en el mismo código quitar los corchetes estoy utilizando para ello replace, pero no me funciona.

```html
<script>
var p = '1. ME GUSTA USAR [ JAVASCRIPT ] VERSION 1.1 "';
var PrinActi = /\[.*?\]/g;
var PrinAct2 = p.match(PrinActi);
var PrinAct3 = PrinAct2.replace('[', '').replace(']', '');;
console.log(PrinAct3);
</script>
```

La idea de todo esto es obtener lo que esta en corchetes y luego quitarle los corchetes, de obtener simplemente la palabra JavaScript puedo utilizar esto:

```
var PrinActi = /\bJAVASCRIPT/;
```

Y no es lo que quiero.

Agradezco mucho la ayuda que puedan brindarme

Comment: Quizas te convenga utilizar el concepto de explode, te dejo una liga donde explican algo referente a este tema:  https://victorroblesweb.es/2015/10/26/explode-en-javascript/  .  Espero que te ayude. Saludos

Comment: Es algo similar, pero con la respuesta de @FranAcuna pude solventar, gracias

Comment: De nada. En lo que se pueda ayudar,  y si hay otra mejor alternativa pues que mejor, Así aprendemos todos algo nuevo.

Comment: Exactamente aprender

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recuerdo que la documentación siempre es nuestro mejor amiga, si leemos la documentación de [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) te darás cuenta de que se devuelve un `array` con los resultados... Si el resultado es único puedes acceder a este elemento único haciendo:

```
var PrinAct2 = p.match(PrinActi)[0];
```

El error que obtienes:

> "Uncaught TypeError: PrinAct2.replace is not a function"

Ocurre porque el método `replace()` es parte de un objeto de tipo `string` y no de un objeto `array` como el que devuelve la función `match()`, por lo tanto no se puede encontrar el método.

```js
var p = '1. ME GUSTA USAR [ JAVASCRIPT ] VERSION 1.1 "';
var PrinActi = /\[.*?\]/g;
var PrinAct2 = p.match(PrinActi)[0];
var PrinAct3 = PrinAct2.replace('[', '').replace(']', '');;
console.log(PrinAct3);
```

Comment: muchas gracias, habia leido sobre match() en el mismo link pero veo que no muy bien me falto el array, de igual manera gracias nuevamente sere mas atento